# How to set scrollbar height on ScrollView in android

Tags: android, android-scrollview

How to set scrollbar height on ScrollView in android.
I have set a custom color for scrollbar of ScrollView using     android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scrollbar"

below is scrollbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="rectangle"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    >
    <gradient
        android:angle="45"
        android:centerColor="#65FF8215"
        android:endColor="#87FD2125"
        android:startColor="#65FF8215"
        />
    <corners android:radius="20dp" />
</shape>
```

How can i change the height of scrollbar ? I want to set height of scrollbar as per this image [image]

Comment: Won't [this](https://github.com/turing-tech/MaterialScrollBar) help you?

Comment: nopes its a recylerview i need for scrollview, problem is default height of scroll bar is too high for slight scrollable content